# SELECT DISTINCT and CONCAT don't return value correcly

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct, concatenation

I have a DataBase with this values:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
Id CHAR (50),
Time TIMESTAMP ,
Value CHAR (50)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('JOE', '2015-06-05 15:36:21', "ZONE1");
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('ANNA', '2015-06-05 14:27:35', "ZONE2");
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('JOE','2015-06-05 16:27:36', "ZONE2");
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('ANNA', '2015-06-05 14:45:31',"ZONE1");
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('JOE','2015-06-05 11:12:31', "ZONE4");
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('ANNA', '2015-06-05 10:25:21',"ZONE3");
```

I like to find users in the last Zone

I try with this SQL intruction:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Id), MAX(Time) AS Time,
CONCAT('{ "Time":"', DATE_FORMAT(Time, '%Y-%e-%d %h:%i:%s'), '", "ID":"',     CAST(Id AS CHAR), '", "Zone":"', Value, '" }') json
FROM test
GROUP BY Id;
```

But, it's the return:

```
|   Id |                   Time |                                                         json |

|------|------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

| ANNA | June, 05 2015 14:45:31 | { "Time":"2015-5-05 02:27:35", "ID":"ANNA", "Zone":"ZONE2" } |

|  JOE | June, 05 2015 16:27:36 |  { "Time":"2015-5-05 03:36:21", "ID":"JOE", "Zone":"ZONE1" } |
```

I don't understand why..... It's return with different dates unordered
 in the third colum...

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS / database backend are you using?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b78/7

Comment: MYSQL5.1.61. But, I test this test in other testing sql server and have the same result...

Comment: Fair enough, but it may impact the answers you receive.

Comment: Hi @Josep I edited my answer on AndriyM suggestion there is much better solution for this type of problem so take a look on my edit. Hope my first part of answer didn't cause any problem :) GL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly you want to do something like this:

```
  SELECT Id, Time,
         CONCAT('{ "Time":"', DATE_FORMAT(Time, '%Y-%e-%d %h:%i:%s'), '", "ID":"', CAST(Id AS CHAR), '", "Zone":"', Value, '" }') json
  FROM (SELECT * 
        FROM test 
        ORDER BY Time DESC) as t
  GROUP BY Id;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b78/11) to see how it's work...

GL!

**P.S.** (edit) You don't need to use DISTINCT and GROUP BY function at the same time they do the same job... Also they select values from the first row in the group so when you want to select values from the row where you have some value (like your MAX(time)) you just place it on the top in ordering. I did that in this subquery

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM test 
 ORDER BY Time DESC) as t
```

**EDIT:** Hi again, on Andriy suggestion in comment I figured out that my first answer isn't the best solution for this problem. So thanks to Andriy I come back with much better and secure solution.

First one is correlated subquery:

```
SELECT Id, Time,
       CONCAT('{ "Time":"', DATE_FORMAT(Time, '%Y-%e-%d %h:%i:%s'), '", "ID":"', CAST(Id AS CHAR), '", "Zone":"', Value, '" }') json
FROM test t1
WHERE Time = (SELECT MAX(t2.Time)
              FROM test t2
              WHERE t1.id = t2.id);
```

And the second uncorrelated subquery:

```
 SELECT t1.Id, t1.Time,
       CONCAT('{ "Time":"', DATE_FORMAT(t1.Time, '%Y-%e-%d %h:%i:%s'), '", "ID":"', CAST(t1.Id AS CHAR), '", "Zone":"', t1.Value, '" }') json
 FROM test t1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(Time) AS Time
             FROM test
             GROUP BY id) AS t2
 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.Time = t2.Time;
```

More about this you can read [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), there is three way to solve this type of problem I wrote you a query for first and second way and let you LEFT JOIN to play a little with that :)

And [here is SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b78/17) to see how this new solution work.

And again credit to Andriy M for suggestion that is not smart to use Group by and Order clause for this...

GL!

Comment: @Josep You're welcome :) I'm glad that I could help. If  answer helps you please mark it as useful

Comment: @Josep and Aleksandar: Although this is a known technique, it has never been confirmed by the manuals to always work. The behaviour may change without a warning in a new version and you may not know what the problem is.

Comment: @AndriyM ohh tnx for note i remeber I already solved similar problem in other way... I know what you mean I don't have time today but I will imrove my answer tomorow. I know there is a better way to select row with max time without ordering and than group by. Thanks again and I hope that wont couse much trable for Joseph :)

Comment: @AndriyM Hi again I edited my answer hope you think on this when you make suggestion... Thanks for that :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I agree with both of your additional suggestions as reliable and consistent.

Comment: @AndriyM Well I still learn and have to learn a lot of thinks, often I do first think that cross my mind that could solve problem, and don't think about the consequences that can produce. I already have similar situation like this. And that's great think here, we have guys like you who give us tips what's good and where we go wrong, that's why I like to be around here I learn a lot just from reading answers. Thanks again for remind me about how to solve problem like this :)  GL